# Не срабатывает AJAX JQuery в IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Есть такой код:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "colloborator_find.html",
        data: "cool_name=" + collNmeValue + "&user_id=6148914691236517121",
        dataType : 'text',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
});
```

В Chrome работает корректно, но в IE приходит пустой ответ. Посмотрел запрос Fiddler'ом, вижу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему в IE отсылается в битой кодировке, из-за этого в ответ приходит пустой ответ, т.к. по данному запросу ничего не находит.
С чем может быть связана проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте `<meta http-equiv="Cоntent-Type" cоntent=text/html; charset="utf-8">` в хедере прописать. Но лучше не использовать русских символов url.

Comment: @Mikl, тогда может лучше предавать POST запросом?

Comment: еще конечно поможет base64

Answer (score 1):

Сделал отправку POST запросом, заработало.